# Stable H323 Clients?

Tags: software-rec

Are there any H323 clients that are stable (don't crash all the time)?

I only found Ekiga, but people in my work group are telling me that it is unusable, because it is crashing all the time.

Is there a stable client? Can be commercial.

Comment: I only found the [videoconferencing] tag after posting an answer. You can consider stating it clearly in the text.

Answer (score 3):

For voice calls, you can try [YATE](http://yate.null.ro/pmwiki/). It was initially meant to work server-side, but with Qt-interface and heavily modular architecture, it works great as SIP, XMPP and H.323 client. It's also precompiled for Windows (if you've got any coworkers that use them) and works fine out of the box. On linux, you may try the latest git version, but compilation for h323 may be a bit tricky. AFAIK, there are also deb and rpm packages available.

There are many, many more things that you can do with YATE, you can find more info at their wiki and mailing list. Also, feel free to ask for anything on #yate channel on Freenode.

Answer (score 3):

i've been looking as well, for several weeks now.  this is h323, and video.  if you don't need h323, or you don't need video, it's a completely different story and you have lots of options.

depending on the OS, and having downloaded hundreds of megabytes of both source code and applications, across all 3 main OSes linux, windows and macosx, here's what i've found works:

- linux - the choice is ekiga.  that's all you get.  there *are* no other working video h323 clients, and ekiga isn't massively stable at that.
- macosx - there is xmeeting. get version 0.42 because it's slightly better.
- windows - myphone3 from openmcu.ru works very very well.  it's hell to find, because the site's in russian and isn't indexed very well, plus the name "myphone" is coming up with all sorts of crap in google search engines which makes it even harder to find.  i tried 3.0.9 and it works really well.  http://openmcu.ru/public/myphone3/

now if you didn't mind using SIP instead, then there are a hell of a lot more options.  ekiga works pretty well, and jitsi works pretty well across all 3 platforms... but there are no stable videoconferencing servers for linux!  although asterisk 10 and above now have "app_confbridge", you *have* to use the exact same CODECs for video because app_confbridge merely does "pass-through" of the video data (broadcasts to all connected clients).

the only stable decent videoconferencing server i could find was openmcu - but not the standard version: only the version on openmcu.ru, found here: http://openmcu.ru/public/sources/

good luck - and if you find anything better please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

An update to the answer above: opencmu is now called "VideoSwitch" and located at https://videoswitch.ru/.

It also has Linux installation available here: https://wiki.videoswitch.ru/ru/install/bin_linux (with Russian documentation). Source code is here: https://github.com/muggot/openmcu